# Crowdrender Install?

Tags: add-on, linux

Can someone walk me through how can I install the crowdrender add on in Linux Mint! When I try to install it, it gives me an error.

Comment: Give us the error message, please.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth it says IMPORT ERROR:- CROWD RENDER IS UNABLE TO RUN BECAUSE IT CANNOT IMPORT NECESSARY COMPONENTS

Answer (score 1):

James from Crowdrender here, apologies for the late entrance but i jst found this post today, amazing what you find when you google your own org's name :P

Ok, the error you describe means that for some reason a critical component can't be imported. This can happen sometimes if the version of python in blender is not supported by our addon. We have (hopefully) fixed this now and there is a new version (v017) available from our website. This version supports a much larger range of python versions that are bundled with blender.

https://www.crowd-render.com/download

EDIT

One other thing to note is that if you use a 32 bit version of blender, Crowdrender will spit a very similar error stating that it cannot import some of it's components, this is because we only support 64 bit and as a result, when a 32 bit version of blender tries to use Crowdrender, it will not be able to find the 32 bit components, simply because, they aren't there!

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a 10 year old laptop which I use so crowdrender would be a great help. I'm looking forward to installing it. I'll keep you posted. Keep on the great work!!!!   Cheers, Frost

Comment: No worries @Frost :D, let us know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

On the crowd-render site I found the following:

> This article shows how to find the computer name for linux using the hostname command via a terminal or shell.
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/hostname.htm

and

> Finding the IP Address.
>   For linux operating systems, try this article.
>   https://www.linuxtrainingacademy.com/determine-public-ip-address-command-line-curl/

There are also video tuts on YouTube. If the above fails, get help on https://www.crowd-render.com/forum-1